# Firebase Auth Reset Password (Flutter) - Get the new password

Tags: flutter, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, passwords

In my Flutter app, there's an admin who creates employee accounts including their passwords. They can however change their passwords later.

The admin can also remove employees

```
await FirebaseAuth.instance
                                .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                                    email: employee.email,
                                    password: employee.password);
                            await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.delete();
```

I call the signInWithEmailAndPassword with the employee email & password & then delete the user from the admin panel

However, if the employee resets the password, the admin can no longer remove this employee as I lose track of the new password

How can I get the new password when someone calls

```
 await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .sendPasswordResetEmail(email: email,)
        .then((value) {});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty odd! Why would an admin need to know the passwords of every employee?

I'd suggest you set up a backend cloud function to do the removal process. On Firebase Admin SDK you can simply call the `deleteUser` method on the Auth object.

```js
getAuth()
  .deleteUser(uid)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Successfully deleted user');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error deleting user:', error);
  });
```

Here's the detailed document: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user

Comment: How do i get the uid??
i have company collections and inside there are lists of employees having an eid

Comment: That's the case in erp/crm systems i've seen...admin creates employee account -> credentials are sent by email -> employee can change them later and admin no longer knows of it...
But here my problem is once they change their password with Firebase Auth reset password, how can i get that password

Comment: Hey, the thing is you don't have to know their password when you're using Admin SDK. You just have to delete the user with the uid associated with their account.

Comment: i want it to be automated i don't want to manually remove them... once the remove process of the employee is done I want everything related to him/her to be removed including the auth part :@